# What will be width for every devices in bootstrap 3 for responsive if I put container width for large 940 px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

What will be width for every devices in bootstrap 3 for responsive if I put .container max-width for large 940 px?
**What will be the max-width size in *media query* for medium, small and extra small devices????**

because I want to write media query for every devices for fixing some problem.

Please give answer with code of media query of this...

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Why do you need a max-width?

Comment: I am using .container max width 940px. but for making it responsive I want to use it. Am I wrong??? what should I do if I want to write something in media query? I want to mention it that I am new for bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the media-queries you'll find in core css. You'll have to set your custom widths in order to fix your problem.
If you need to keep proportions, try using Photoshop to scale your 940px, to smallest sizes.
Personally, even when it is okay you overwrite the largest container, I wouldn't overwrite .container for smallest devices. But it depends on you.

You'll have to add a .container and set your custom width inside each media-query.

```
/*==================================================
=            Bootstrap 3 Media Queries             =
==================================================*/

    /*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

    }
```

.

```
    /*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is more effective for responsive, min-width or max-width? Should I use only min-width for media query?

Comment: It depends if you started writing css styles for mobile first or desktop. Min-width if it's mobile first. Max-width if not. Choose whatever fixes your problem.

Comment: I have started writing css for desktop and want to make it responsive for tablet and mobile, now what will I use, min-width or max-width? Remember, I am using max-width of .container 940px for desktop.

Comment: max-width, in the order I pasted after: Non-Mobile First Method.

Comment: Ok then I am using max-width. Thanks for your help.